# How to know what's a valid APC key?

Tags: php, apc

I first thought that any string would be a valid APC key, but it turns out that it's not the case:

```php
var_export(apc_store('a\b:c', 1));  // true
var_export(apc_store('a\b::c', 1)); // false
```

Looks like it's not a matter of characters, as both `\` and `:` are accepted, it's just *some* combinations of characters that are just refused.

Is there an explanation on why the second one doesn't work, and even better, a documentation on what's accepted and what's not?

Note: this is the result I get on PHP 5.4.11, Zend Server CE 6.0.1, Windows.

Comment: Works on my system - PHP 5.4.6, APC 3.1.13. What's the key name you see if you dump `apc_cache_info('user')` ?

Comment: Interesting, `apc_cache_info()` and `apc_cache_info('user')` both return an empty array on my system. And `phpinfo()` just shows an empty table entry for APC. This Zend Server is weird.